# Does Authorization in HttpPost is required everytime?

Tags: java, apache, https, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a simple http post code. I have some basic questions.

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic username:password");
httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost); 
httpClient.close();
```

Does the authorization needs to be specified for every post request ? Is there a way to reuse authorization credentials for subsequent post requests once the connection is established for the first request? Does the server keeps the authorization from specific client active for a duration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your http server code and how it processes each request; the easiest approach is maybe to just set a [cookie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie) in your response from server (or some other identifier value) and just send that value in the consecutive requests after the first successful authorization;